# How to print on Zebra ZM400 from javascript or PHP through printer IP?

Tags: php, javascript, printing, zebra-printers

I know there are some almost similar threads, but none is the same and none has helped me.
I have to print tickets with Zebra ZM400 printer but I did not managed to do this in the last two days. Since I didnt find clear and working solutions on the net, I hope you guys can give me a solution.
I have tried two methods:

1. jZebra: I've set the printer name then pressed print, but I always get the error: "Printer does not accept job". Did not get any solution for it. And I think this would be a printover USB and not IP, since I could not find any setting to adjust the printer's IP address.
2. I've tried to print with the following class, but nothing happens even when trying the sample code: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2540-PHP-Abstraction-for-printing-documents.html . I get PHP timeout error. Can't even find the printer.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks you!

Comment: big difference php and javascript, which do you want to use?

Comment: any of it if it works through IP. Thanks

Comment: did you follow these instructions to add the generic text driver?  http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialRawXP

Comment: Thanks Ovi, that was the problem, it's the first time I work with print servers, so I didn't really know how to set it up properly. It was set up as on server, but not added like a local printer which can be used like any other.